# libtool not found. Please install libtool

Tags: package, install

Linux Mint 21

Emacs 27.1

I want to install package "vterm".

Here my init.el

```
(use-package use-package-ensure-system-package
  :ensure t)

(use-package vterm
  :ensure t
  :ensure-system-package libtool-bin)
```

As you can see before install vterm, will be install `libtool-bin`.

But when I restart Emacs I get error:

```
-- System libvterm not found: libvterm will be downloaded and compiled as part of the build process
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:71 (message):
  libtool not found.  Please install libtool


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/alexei/.emacs.d/elpa/vterm-20230217.228/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
/home/alexei/.emacs.d/elpa/vterm-20230217.228
```

P.S.
**Synaptic Project Manager** success found `libtool-bin`

[image]

Comment: Does your (system) package manager know about the `libtool-bin` package?  Can you see it listed with `synaptic`, for example?

Comment: @FranBurstall I was updated my post

Comment: Then install it from `synaptic` and see if `vterm` then builds.  Optionally report the issue to the `use-package-ensure-system-package` maintainers.

Comment: FTR, I've had the same issue on Debian. When installed with `apt install elpa-vterm`, it was all fine, but when trying from Emacs: same problem as in the OP. `libtool` was installed on the system, of course, but `libtool-bin` was also needed, as @FranBurstall said.